# what do we mean by "experiment" and "sub-experiment" in probability?

Tags: probability

Here is a quote from the book Introduction to Probability by Blitzstein and Hwang, which makes two references to the notion of a "sub-experiment".

I understand everything in this quote, but I wonder if I am missing some of the intuition behind thinking of things in terms of "experiments" and "sub-experiments". To put it another way, I am not sure that I could give a sufficiently nuanced definition of either term.

So, what do we mean by "an experiment" or "a sub-experiment" in combinatorics/probability, and what are the necessary conditions that must hold to be able to think of something as a sub-experiment, in particular?

> Theorem 1.4.5 (Sampling with replacement). Consider n objects and
>   making k choices from them, one at a time with replacement (i.e.,
>   choosing a certain object does not preclude it from being chosen
>   again). Then there are $n^{k}$ possible outcomes. For example, imagine a
>   jar with n balls, labeled from 1 to n. We sample balls one at a time
>   with replacement, meaning that each time a ball is chosen, it is
>   returned to the jar.
>
> Each sampled ball is a sub-experiment with n possible outcomes, and
>   there are k sub-experiments. Thus, by the multiplication rule there
>   are $n^{k}$ ways to obtain a sample of size k.
>
> Theorem 1.4.6 (Sampling without replacement). Consider n objects and
>   making k choices from them, one at a time without replacement (i.e.,
>   choosing a certain object precludes it from being chosen again). Then
>   there are n(n-1)... (n-k+1) possible outcomes, for k <= n (and 0
>   possibilities for k > n).
>
> This result also follows directly from the multiplication rule: each
>   sampled ball is again a sub-experiment, and the number of possible
>   outcomes decreases by 1 each time.

Comment: The author could have avoided the term "sub-experiment" entirely, just by saying something like "there are $n$ possible choices for each ball, and we are choosing $k$ balls, so all together there are $n^k$ possible outcomes." Maybe this would have avoided the confusion.

Comment: No it would have avoided what sub-experiment meant, but it would not have cleared what experiment actually meant.

Answer (score 1):

An "experiment" in this sense is some activity that has a certain set of outcomes, which we want to model using probabilities.  An experiment might be divided into parts, which we would call sub-experiments; each sub-experiment has an outcome, and the outcome of the experiment 
is constructed from the outcomes of the sub-experiments.  These sub-experiments
might be separated in time (first you do this, then that, ...), but this is not necessary: the division into sub-experiments might only be conceptual.

In the example given, the experiment consists of drawing $k$ balls with replacement from a jar containing balls numbered $1$ to $n$.  The outcome of the experiment is the list of $k$ numbers drawn.  Each drawing can be considered as a sub-experiment, 
whose outcome is one number.  You put the outcomes of the sub-experiments together and you get the outcome of the experiment.

Comment: What do you mean by "in this sense" ? Is the definition of experiment is subject to interpretation ? The word "experiment" comes up very frequently in probability, i guess the op is trying to find a rigorous definition that is not subject to interpretation.